# Set range in VBA sort

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, set

I am trying to sort data in Excel VBA.  My sheet could have a variable amount of data so I am using the `Range.End` method to find the last row/ column of the sheet.  Though, when I try to set the range for the sort it gives me an Object Required error and I am not sure why.  I have pasted my code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
With Sheet9.Sort
    .SetRange (Sheet9.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=rng2, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED BASED ON COMMENTS:

I entered the below code into a mock spreadsheet that I created and it seems to work fine. The error described in the comments: `Sort Reference is not valid` indicates that there's possibly an issue in defining the key. Try to use my code (replace with necessary information) and let me know if it works.

```
Sub Doit()

    Set rng2 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")

    With Sheet1.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rng2, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Based on the ability to use `.End` for both rows and columns, I assume you have a contiguous data set. If so, instead of complicating matters, simply use:

`Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to set your range object.

This recognizes the entire dataset that is built around `Range("A1")`

Comment: @Philip `Sheet9` implicitly refers to the 9th sheet of your workbook.  Do you have 9 sheets in your workbook?  Does `Sheets(9)` return an "subscript out of range" error?

Comment: Yes `Sheet9` is a valid sheet.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Is it possible that `Key:=rng2` is causing the error? Does `rng2` refer to a range on `Sheet9`

Comment: No the line that throws the error is:  `.SetRange (Sheet9.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)`

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I remove the parenthesis around `Sheet9.Range("A1").CurrentRegion` it seems to work. Can you test that and report back?

Comment: Ok now it works but when it tries to apply it it says the sort reference is not valid...Any thoughts?

Comment: I am trying to multi column sort a table and I am having problems with the .setRange for the table.  With probability_table.Sort
            .SortFields.Add Key:=probability_table.Range(program_index), Order:=xlAscending .SetRange Range("B6").Header = xlYes .Apply end with